# D3 - move y-axis labels above line

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/3gikXOR8EydIcA3wcBMb?p=preview

The numbers on the y axis are in the centre of the grid line.

I can change the padding with

```
.tickPadding(5)
```

Can I change the vertical position of the numbers so they bottom of the number is on the same level as the grid line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a `dy` attribute to the text items

```
  chart.append("g")
    .classed('y-axis', true)
    .call(y_axis)
    .selectAll('text')
    .attr('dy', '-0.3em');
```